# How to make Node.js backend JavaScript wait for my bash script to finish before doing anything else

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, express

Through a Node.js code, I am running 3 bash commands. Part of the file is shown below:

```
exec(str,
function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('stdout:'+stdout);
    console.log('stderr:'+stderr);
    if(error!=null){
        console.log('exec error: '+error);
    }
exec('bash create_q_out_list.sh',
    function(error, stdout, stderr){
        console.log('stdout:'+stdout);
        console.log('stderr:'+stderr);
        if(error!=null){
            console.log('exec error: '+error);
        }
exec('bash replaceString.sh',
    function(error, stdout, stderr){
        console.log('stdout:'+stdout);
        console.log('stderr:'+stderr);
        if(error!=null){
            console.log('exec error: '+error);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

In the above code, 'bash replaceString.sh' generates an HTML file that I am displaying in an Iframe of my Home webpage. 
But, sometimes, before the new file is generated (i.e. 3rd bash command is finished), JS shows my old file on the Iframe. ***So, at the end even though my HTML file contains the correct content, old content has already been displayed.***

Given below is the Iframe :

```
<iframe id='svg_frame' src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/render.html"></iframe>
```

Also, this is part of my server(**render.html** is the file that is being generated by the 3rd bash command):

```
app.get('/render.html', (req, res) =>{
  const rend = fs.readFileSync('./render.html');
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader = ('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.write(rend);
  res.end();
});
```

*I want the Node.js to wait for the new render.html file to be generated before showing anything on the Iframe.*

Comment: why on earth are you using javascript to execute bash? what ever it is that your trying to do... don't.

Comment: @Plixxer How should I execute them then??

Comment: Javascript is on the client side. Bash is on the server side.
If your intent is that your clients have server sided scripts on their machine, dont.
You should be using a server sided language to call server sided scripts ( thus resulting in you probably not needed to execute bash at all )

Comment: @Plixxer I have Node.js file on the server side. It is calling a JavaScript file which is running my bash scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda agree with @Plixxer's statment, if it's a simple operation like replacing a string, just stick with JS on node, but regardless, I think your issue is in

```
app.get('/render.html', (req, res) =>{
  const rend = fs.readFileSync('./render.html');
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader = ('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.write(rend);
  res.end();
});
```

specifically here `const rend = fs.readFileSync('./render.html');`

if that file exists BEFORE you replace stuff with your bash script, node will just get it from the file system and serve it to the client, it doesn't know that there is something going on in the background), that means you would have to do your replace within the `app.get()` block:

```
app.get('/render.html', (req, res) =>{
  let rend = fs.readFileSync('./render.html');
  rend = rend.replace('<regex or whatever you are replacing in bash>', '<replacment, can be a function as well!>');
  // or of course execute your bash replacement script here!
  //   exec('bash replaceString.sh', rend,
  //     function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  //       console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  //       console.log('stderr:', stderr);
  //       if ( error !== null ) {
  //           console.log('exec error:', error);
  //       }
  //     }
  //   );
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader = ('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.write(rend);
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: Why there are two exec? What is the use of first exec(rend)?

Comment: Sorry, just copied your code, leftover, gonna fix =)

Comment: It isn't working. It is giving me ENOENT error: file doesn't exist. My exec() command creates that file. Also, I put the readFileSync() statement after my exec() to ensure that the file exists

Comment: I used execSync() instead of exec(). And I included everything in the server script only. It works fine. Thanks